# Linking to local files from HTTP fetched pages with IE9

Tags: http, hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, file-uri

One of my clients has an intranet-only website that contains many links to files on the local network, in the form of `<a href="file://localfileserver/importantdocument.doc">Link</a>`.  However, none of the links seem to work anymore in **IE9**. I know all the other browsers refuse to allow linking to local files from pages fetched over HTTP, is this the case in the newest version of IE as well?

All the links still work fine on **IE8**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140701000000*/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx). The change here was also made to IE8, so I'm guessing that the Zone settings you have are configured differently between the IE8 and IE9 machines.

[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20140701000000*/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx) https://web.archive.org/web/20140813113355/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx

Comment: Yes, adjusting the zone settings fixed the problem. Thank you!